# Como redirecionar através duma notificação?

Tags: php, facebook, notificação

Estou a enviar notificações aos usuários cadastrados através do Facebook, sobre novos eventos. Como faço para redirecionar o usuário para a URL do evento, enviado através da API do Facebook?

```
private function sendNotification($userFbId, $message, $url){
    $attachment = array(
      'access_token' => Configure::read('fb_id').'|'.Configure::read('fb_secret'),
      'href' => $url, 
      'template' => $message,
    );
    try {
        $api = $this->Facebook->api('/'.$userFbId.'/notifications/', 'POST',  $attachment);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $api = $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $api;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer que o facebook redirecione o usuário, após ser convidado pela notificação, para o evento no facebook? Veja isso: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Embaixo do `$api  = (...)`, se você colocar `header("Location: {$url}");` funciona?

Comment: @Lollipop Eu cadastro um evento no site e envio uma notificação aos usuários cadastrados nele, através do Facebook. Ao enviar uma notificação no Facebook, quero que redirecione o usuário para a url que informo.

Comment: Acho que é só usar header amigo passando a url com os parametros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O link das notificações só podem levar para um link relativo da própria canvas do app.

"The relative path/GET params of the target (for example, 'index.html?gift_id=123', or '?gift_id=123')..."
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications#impl

E como a canvas é um iframe, não dá nem pra redirecionar =/

Comment: Então há como abrir o link enviado na notificação, dentro do canvas? Ou seja, dentro da app no Facebook?

Comment: Isso. Lá nas configurações do seu app, onde você configurou a URL da canvas, você pode apontar para qualquer link dentro dessa url bem como passar parâmetros via get pra index da sua canvas, etc.